# How to cast an Image in Chromecast?

Tags: c#, chromecast

I am using SharpCaster code. I have a Chromecast to test with. I can successfully find and connect to the Chromecast, but I can't figure out how to simply Display Image . If there any solution?

Reference:
[SharpCaster](https://github.com/Tapanila/SharpCaster)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers. Also, please take time to visit the official documentation of [Google Cast API](https://developers.google.com/cast/) to learn more about it.

Comment: Trouble sending a local image to chrome cast